# DBCC SHRINKFILE with emptyfile generating filegroup is full errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dbcc

I have been using DBCC SHRINKFILE with EMPTYFILE to move data from one secondary data files data to another. There is currently four files in the filegroup and there is over 1TB free of space between those files.

Oddly, I've had the system alert me that the filegroup that these files belongs to is full and that no space could be allocated for a table (user) table.

I've used this numerous times before and never had this happen and some googling couldn't seem to find any other incidents that people had reported. Anybody have any ideas?

Version of SQL Server is 2008R2

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you are shrinking a data file. 99% of the time this is bad. Also, after you shrunk, what is the max file size set to for each data file? What's the auto growth (% or MB)

Comment: Yes I know it is bad as it causes fragmentation and unnecessary I/O but long story I have some business people that want to move data files from one drive to another without downtime.  This way achieves that (though it's NOT what should be done - but my hands are tied).  Regardless of my reasons, I'm unsure why this error would occur with an online operation.

Comment: Autogrowth is set to 5GB, no max file size.  This pertains to only one of the files though, the other files have no autogrowth enabled.

Comment: Ok, i voted to move this to dba.stackexchange, but i'm still trying to figure out how shrinking the data file enables you to move it from one drive to another.

Comment: Create a new file on new drive, use shrinkfile with emptyfile on the old data file.  It doesn't move the data 1-to-1, but in the end you remove the old data file and you are left with the much of the data moved to the new data file on the new drive.  Again - while this might seem nifty, it's a REALLY bad idea, but again I have no choice.

Comment: Oh i see now, I didn't know you were creating a new datafile. Since you said that the *filegroup* was full, note that if it's in the PRIMARY filegroup, that's where TEMPDB lives by default too, so maybe it wasn't your user database.  I've only seen this error specify the database though--so you should see that

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem. It turned out that a nightly maintenance process was issuing an ALTER INDEX command on an index in the same file while the DBCC SHRINKFILE WITH EMPTYFILE was running. Makes sense that ALTER INDEX wouldn't work while the file is marked to not accept new data.

In our environment, we resolved this by preventing the nightly maintenance process from issuing this command and issuing it manually outside of the time that we allow the SHRINKFILE to run.